# Ruby 1.8.7 multiline blocks

Tags: ruby

So I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to write a multiline block that loops through a file and executes an if statement to get the last line number of each string in the file

```
i = 0

IO.foreach("testfile.log") {|line|
  if line.include? str1
    x = i
  elsif line.include? str2 and line.include? str3
    y = i
  end

  i++
}
```

When i try to execute the script, I get the following error at the end of the block:

error syntax error, unexpected '}'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I know this is off topic, but [1.8.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/) is end of life. Consider upgrading to Ruby 2.

Comment: @squiguy It's gone well beyond end-of-life now and it's actually hazardous to use since it's not getting any patches.

Comment: @squiguy yea its on an old O.S. that only supports 1.8.7 and would be a hassle to upgrade otherwise I would

Comment: This exact same question gets asked soooo often over and over and over and over again here in SO. I'd really like to know which braindead tutorial teaches this stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i++` is not valid Ruby. Try `i += 1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

That's bad form, if you need a multi-line block

```
i = 0
IO.foreach("testfile.log") do |line|
  if line.include? str1
    x = i
  elsif line.include? str2 and line.include? str3
    y = i
  end
  i+=1 # courtesy of Michael Kohl
end
```

Comment: is there any reason for that or is it just convention / aesthetic

Comment: Also why not `readlines("testfile.log").each_with_index do |line, i| ` then there is not need for `i` at all outside of the block.

Comment: aesthetic? Not sure was passing a block in braces to avoid do, end for one liners or vice versa???. No reason at all not to use each_with_index, wasn't the question I was answering though.